# How would I get the IP Address of a Heroku Dyno acting as a server?

Tags: heroku, ip-address

I have attempted to host a minecraft server on heroku which means I would need the external IP address of the dyno if I understand this correctly. However upon getting the external IP using https://httpbin.org/ip from the Heroku CLI, the minecraft client doesnt seem to be pinging it. I am confused on which IP address I would need to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to use something like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).